# Passing Fortran arrays to C

Tags: c, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I am having a lot of trouble passing Fortran arrays to a C program. From what I have gathered from previous posts is the inclusion of the interface. That got rid of some of my problems. However, I cannot seem to figure out how to pass these arrays properly or access their values correctly inside C.

```
program f_call_c
  implicit none


  interface
     subroutine cfun(x,len) bind( c )
       use,intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
       implicit none
       integer( c_int) :: len
       real(c_double) :: x(0:3,0:len)
     end subroutine   cfun

     subroutine vec(r,len) bind(c)
       use,intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
       implicit none
       integer(c_int) :: len
       real(c_double) :: r(0:len)
     end subroutine vec


  end interface


  double precision, allocatable :: x(:,:),r(:)
  integer :: len,row,i,j

  len = 7
  allocate(x(0:3,0:len))
  allocate(r(0:len))

  do i =0,len
     r(i) = i
  enddo


  do i = 0,len
     do j = 0,3
        x(j,i) = j+i
     enddo
  enddo

  call vec(r,%val(len) )

  row = 3
  call cfun(x,%val(len))
end program f_call_c


#include <stdio.h>
void cfun(double **x,const int len)
{
  printf("%d\n", len);
  printf("This is in C function cfun...\n");


  for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
      printf(" %d\n  %d\n  %d\n", x[0][i]);

    }
}

void vec(  double *r[],const int len )
{
  printf("This is in C function vec...\n");

  printf("%d\n", len);

  for(int i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
       printf(" %d\n", r[i]);

    }

}
```

Currently, the output is

```
    Fortran calling C, passing
 r at           0 is   0.0000000000000000     
 r at           1 is   1.0000000000000000     
 r at           2 is   2.0000000000000000     
 r at           3 is   3.0000000000000000     
 r at           4 is   4.0000000000000000     
 r at           5 is   5.0000000000000000     
 r at           6 is   6.0000000000000000     
 r at           7 is   7.0000000000000000     
This is in C function vec...
7
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
7
This is in C function cfun...
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can't recieve a fortran array in c as `double **`, it should be `double *`, so try this

```
#include <stdio.h>

void cfun(double *x, const int len)
{
    printf("%d\n", len);
    printf("This is in C function cfun...\n");

    for (int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++)
    {
        printf(" %d\n  %d\n  %d\n", x[i]);
    }
}
```

in fact if you have a c `double **` array of pointers you should join the arrays into a single array to pass it to fortran, see for example how to use [Lapack](http://www.physics.orst.edu/~rubin/nacphy/lapack/codes/linear-c.html) in c.

The reason is that in in a fortran 2d array is stored contiguously, whereas in c `double **` is an array of pointers, and hence the values are not contiguously stored.

Note that when printing the values, you will print wrong values, because you are not using the appropriate format specifier for `double` you should fix the `printf` line to make it look like this

```
printf(" %f\n  %f\n  %f\n", x[i]);
```

Comment: So I made the changes you suggested, and it doesn't seg fault at least. In both void functions i pass a double *. Now I get  an output of 906461184 seven times in both functions. Is it outputting a memory address?

Comment: because you are using the wrong format specifier, I will update my answer.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Its printing off reasonable values. However, I am still confused because x is defined as a matrix in the fortran code, but seems to be a one dimensional array in the c code. I dont understand how x[i] is being translated. I need it to be like x[0][i] x[1][i] x[2][i], however when I try this i get subscripted value is neither pointer nor array

Comment: Also, the original reason I was trying to experiment with the ** is that I have a c function that has inputs like void function(double **x, double **y, const int len, double *b, const double *w), so I need to figure out how to pass information from fortran to a function like this

Comment: You have to make the `double **` from the data you recieved, for that you need to pass the number of `rows` and the number of `columns` of the 2d  fortran array and build the `double **` array of `double` pointers.

Comment: What you think of as C arrays are really pointers with an array-like syntax. This works ok for single-dimension arrays, but a C two-dimensional array is really an array of pointers to arrays, something not natural to Fortran.